# Python UDFs in Pig

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I've seen the documentatio [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/UDFsUsingScriptingLanguages), but I confess that I feel it rather lacking.  I was wondering if anyone could give me collection of examples as to incorporating Python UDFs into Pig.  In particular

- Prior to Pig 0.10, the boolean type does not exist, but a `FILTER` operation requires the result resolve to a boolean.  Am I forever cursed with returning `1` or `0` and using `FILTER alias BY py_udf.f(field) > 0` if I don't have the latest version?
- Are the `Algebraic`, `Accumulator`, and `Filter` interfaces inaccessible from Python?
- Can I not access the Distributed Cache either?
- What about Store/Load functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python UDFs are quite limited. You cannot use Algebraic or Accumulator interfaces, nor can you write a LoadFunc in Python. For anything more complicated than a map operation you will likely need to resort to a Java UDF.

That said, a more complex Python UDF with a dynamic outputSchema can be found at http://ragrawal.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/on-writing-python-udf-for-pig-a-perspective/. This likely won't help you, but it will give you a better understanding of what Python UDFs can do.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer most of your specific questions, but [this blog post](http://techblug.wordpress.com/2011/08/07/transitive-closure-in-pig/) and linked code contains several good examples of using Pig with Python, and does include usage of Store/Load and their interaction with Python.