# For Apache Pig, how do I write a Load UDF in python

Tags: python, jython, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I want to write a Python UDF Load function for Apache Pig, so that I can use it in the following way in a Pig script:

```
register 'myudfs.py' using jython as myfuncs;
A = load 'data' using myfuncs.myLoader() as line;
```

The [Pig documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/) provides some detail for writing Load UDFs *in Java*, but *not in Python*. I have managed to implement quite useful Eval functions with Python, but I couldn't find anything about how to write Load functions in this language.

Because I have already implemented a few Eval UDFs in Python, I would like to stick to this language for all my UDFs.

Comment: I just found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15792780/65889): According to @Ian_Stevens, LoadFuncs for Pig *cannot* be written in Python. This would explain why the documentation is so silent about it. But is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is true. You can even look at the source to verify.  Notice how [`JythonFunction`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/scripting/jython/JythonFunction.html) extends [`EvalFunc`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/EvalFunc.html) not [`LoadFunc`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/LoadFunc.html).

If I need to use python to handle loading the file(s) I do is something like:

```
register 'myudfs.py' using jython as myudfs ;

A = LOAD 'foo.bar' AS (total:chararray) ; 
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myudf.prepare_input(total) ;
```

To simulate a sudo-LoadFunc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reference to `JythonFunction` makes it really clear.

Comment: To your work around: I tried exactly the same. Trouble is I need special treatment for the 1st line of *each* input file and a global line counter enumerates over all lines in *all files*, so in the `foreach` I have no way to know whether I am on a first line or not. That's why I was hoping to write a real custom `LoadFunc`.

Comment: You are going to need a Java UDF for that.  They are pretty painful to write, but I wrote something that may be close to what you want [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18345721/2336149).  Enumeration can be done with `RANK`.  Is this the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053048/with-apache-pig-how-to-select-and-store-columns-from-a-csv-according-to-header-l)?